# SFTP (SSH) in replacement of FTP (ssh permission)

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I'm currently creating for the company I'm working for a brand new SFTP [1] server in place of old FTP serveur. [2]

Here, anybody could have access to the FTP folder on the server (let's name this \\SERVER\Ftp). This way if you want to share something with another company you can put it in the \\SERVER\Ftp\ftp-user-login-folder\the_file.doc

So now, on the new server (xubuntu 20.04) with SAMBA shared folder "Ftp", still named \\SERVER\Ftp I'm trying to reproduce "kind of" ftp server.

But, any user granted on this serveur via SFTP should have his own $HOME folder where ssh info are stored etc. Ok, lets do this. Now I change the home folder when creating a new user... pointing to the local disk (example /mnt/RAID5-DISK/Local-Network-Shared/Ftp/ftp-user-name). Also Accessible to local network with \\SERVER\Ftp\ftp-user-name\

But all the folder from root/ to the $HOME server (example : /mnt/RAID5-DISK/Local-Network-Shared/Ftp/ftp-user-name) should be own by root, with group root and with rwxr-xr-x permission (755)
But this mean, SAMBA users could not access to this folder anymore...

I' tried to pass sshd config to StrictModes no. But it change nothing.

This start to be a little bit too complicated for users here. Only a root user can create new user on the SFTP (this mean me, i don't want to do that everyweek).

Question (double) :

- Does something more simple exist for this ? (like FileZilla, shared folder for virtual user login/mdp) but with the ssh security ?

OR

- Is it possible to make all the process of user managing and share creating easiest for non geek user here ? where a non geek user can easily create one new SFTP user with shared folder ?

Anyway, thanks for reading me, and thanks in advance for your kindly help.

[1] The old server software was fileZilla under Windows server. Easy to use, add user, add folder, create password and it's done. A 8 years old child could do this.

[2] SSH based, i'm not speaking about FTPS, old fashion FTP with Secure certificate

Comment: FileZilla or WinSCP will still work with an SFTP server by setting the Protocol field to "SFTP – SSH File Transfer Protocol". See [link](https://www.thorntech.com/2020/01/migrate-ftp-to-sftp/).

Comment: Hi, thx for your reply. I don't have a problem to connect a client. But I want to create a server. see here Filezilla : https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=51719

Comment: An SSH server for Linux is of course the OpenSSH server ([link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-openssh-server/) but there are many). FileZilla or WinSCP are supposed to work with them.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my problem is here. I can't configure openSSH server under linux as I need. So I used a VM machine with W10 and FreeFTPd software. It's ugly but it's work. It's user friendly, add user&pass, set folder and it's done.